# Timezone Select List in Ruby by UTC Offset

Tags: ruby, list, select

I would like to have a select listed by offset difference to UTC, like:

```
<select value=1>(GMT 00:00) GMT</select>
<select value=1>(GMT 00:00) Lisbon</select>
<select value=1>(GMT +00:01) Madrid</select>
```

Just like in Rails:
https://signup.37signals.com/highrise/Free/signup/new

We're using Sinatra+Padrino.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all.inject([]) do |result, tz|
  utc_offset = tz.utc_offset / 3600
  result << ["(UTC #{'%.2d' % utc_offset}): #{tz.name}", utc_offset]
end
```

It will produce an array for options_for_select:

```
[["(UTC -11): International Date Line West", -11], ["(UTC -11): Midway Island", -11]...]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
arr = TZInfo::Timezone.all_country_zone_identifiers.collect { |x| x + " " + ActiveSupport::TimeZone[x].formatted_offset }
arr.sort
```

This way you can get all time zones with offset

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this:

```
timezones_diff_and_name = []
  TZInfo::Timezone.all_linked_zones.each do |tz|
    timezones_diff_and_name << {tz.name => tz.current_period.utc_total_offset / (60 * 60)}
  end

  sorted_timezones = timezones_diff_and_name.sort_by { |timezone| timezone.values[0] }

  @timezones = {}
  sorted_timezones.each do |tz|
    diff = tz.values[0]
    name = tz.keys[0]
    @timezones["(GMT#{diff > 0 ? '+':''}#{diff.to_s}h) #{name}"] =  name
  end
```

Do you know any better solution (maybe cleaner/faster)?

Comment: this belongs in your question, not as an answer :)

Comment: I don't think `all_linked_zones` is the right one to use, it gives just a small number of places. You should use one of the other methods. Note, however, that you will have LOTS of items, unless you perform some kind of grouping (several cities in an item, for example).

Answer (score 0):

I made like this which is more user-friendly I think

```
@total_timezones = {}
ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all.uniq(&:utc_offset).each{  |item|
    @total_timezones.merge!({"(UTC"+ item.formatted_offset.to_s + ") " + item.name => item.utc_offset}) 
}
```

And in erb

```
<div class="col-xs-4">
            <select class="form-control" name="tz_offset">
            <%= options_for_select(@total_timezones.each, @timeline_emails.tz_offset) %>
            </select>
</div>
```

And another example without the front part which includes whole timezones including Kiribati Islands `+14` which is out from most used standard timezones.

```
 TZInfo::Timezone.all_country_zone_identifiers.each { |item|  @total_timezones.merge!({"(UTC" +  ActiveSupport::TimeZone[item].formatted_offset + ") " + item => ActiveSupport::TimeZone[item].formatted_offset}) }
 @total_timezones = @total_timezones.sort_by { |key, value| value.scan(/-?\d+/).join.to_i }
```