# Use time_zone with best_in_place

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, timezone, best-in-place

I'm using time zones in my app, and can happily use the built in Rails 3 help method to have a collection of time zones when using a standard form, or even a simple_form.

However, best_in_place needs to have a collection presented to it. Does anyone know how to get the list of time zones so that they can be presented as a collection to best_in_place?

I've been trying something on the lines of the following:

```
best_in_place @account, :time_zone, type: :select, collection: ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all { |e| [e.name] }
```

However, I always seem to get a list but with blank lines. The above was the closest in that BIP takes the value, but it is still empty.

Comment: [This answer may help](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9176964/634824).

Comment: Were you ever able to get this working Michael? I was looking for a solution too

Comment: @pwz2000 were you able to get it working? :)